Lagrange multipliers imply critical point?
Conceptual problem ...
In the lagrange multiplier method, let $x$ be a real n-space variable, looking to minimize $F$ subject to $G=0$, we find crictial points of $F + \lambda G$, sometimes called a Hamiltonian, where $G=0$ defines a manifold. In this context, does the existence of these critical points imply that $F$ restricted to that manifold has a critical point.
Does this still apply on a Hilbert manifold - using lagrange multipliers with the Euler Lagrange technique?
In particular we look at $\int F[x] + \lambda G[x]\ dt$, where $G[x]=0$ is a differential equation and $F[x]$ is a differential operator, and produce from this, using Euler Lagrange, a differential equation, call it $L[x,\lambda]=0$. But, it appears that that differential equation is normally solvable for $\lambda$ given $x$ such that $G[x]=0$. That means the existance of the lagrange multipliers. Which seems to suggest that $F[x]$ is constant. But, it is a generic operator that returns a single real value.
At which point does this reasoning fail?
